# how can i write a native query in spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, native

who can help me to fix the issue . Indeed, I want to write a native query in spring boot of that List findByPatientIdAndNameOrderByMeasuredDateTime(int patientId, String name).

Here my postMan test localhost:8081/trusthealthy/api/clinicals/1/bp

I tried to translate this query result :

"SELECT id, name,value, measured_date_time
FROM clinicaldata
WHERE patient_id=1 AND name= "bp";"

that I got in mySql to a native query in spring boot but it's not working

```
@Query(value = "SELECT id, name, value,measured_date_time FROM clinicaldata WHERE patient_id=1 AND name='bp' " , nativeQuery=true)
List<ClinicalData> findByPatientIdAndNameOrderByMeasuredDateTime(int patientId, String name);
```

Thanks in advance for helping me !

Comment: Your syntax for `@Query` is correct, but none of the parameters of the query are used. What exactly do you mean "it's not working"? How is it not working? Also, how are you calling this query from your service layer?

Comment: In your use case no need of method parameters since your are not passing them dynamically into the query, And can u pls share what exception or problem you are getting while running the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT id, name, value,measured_date_time FROM clinicaldata c WHERE c.patient_id=?1 AND c.name=?2 " , nativeQuery=true)

List <ClinicalData> findByPatientIdAndNameOrderByMeasuredDateTime(int patientId, String name);
```